# How to test functions inside javascript closure

Tags: javascript, tdd, closures

This seems impossible (and it might be), but I'm trying to get into more TDD and I keep hitting a wall with closures.  Say I have the following:

```
function createSomething(init) {
    function privateMethod(param) {
        return init[param];  //assuming this is more complicated, how can you test it?
    }

    function getData() {
        return init.data;
    }

    function getValue(name) {
        if (name === "privateNode" || typeof name !== "string") {
            return "permissionDenied";
        }
        return privateMethod(name);
    }

    return {
        getData : getData,
        getValue: getValue
    };
}
```

Putting aside this code probably isn't the best illustration of my point and assuming "privateMethod" is something much more complicated than what is above, is there any way to run unit tests on methods like "privateMethod" or is the best you can do is to test the object created by createSomething?  I ask because large parts of my application are hidden inside closures.  I'm pretty uninformed in this area, but it seems to me that this is a weak spot for javascript and tdd.
fiddle for the code above without tdd is here: http://jsfiddle.net/QXEKd/

Comment: just saw this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626231/testing-within-a-javascript-closure?rq=1  I might need to modify the question as my focus is a bit different in that I won't be able to smuggle in functions because they will be accessing data available only inside the closure.

Comment: The smuggled function should still have the closure from where it was smuggled from unless you're doing something like the evil `eval`. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rEDMh/).

Comment: The advice I've seen on testing private methods is "don't". Test the only the public interface, leaving you free to refactor the internals.

Comment: It might me worth noting that if you're taking functions out like this for testing purposes only, it might be preferable to comment out or otherwise remove the code to access these before publishing it on your website, so it can't be abused. Also, be aware that `this` will change depending on how a function is invoked, if you are using it.

Comment: @PaulS - thanks, your fiddle looks like enough for me to get a solution going.  Would you mind putting your comment in answer form so I can check it off?

Comment: @Odalrick - I hear that, the issue being I need to hide a lot of data because of the way our API is structured.  The balance isn't favouring only testing the api in my case since this is a SAS application.

Comment: @Shane Yes, pragmatic concerns are always there; which is why I didn't submit it as an answer. Still the desire to test internal methods is a bad smell; maybe the public object should be broken into helpers that can be tested separately. You'd get testablility and cleaner code.

Comment: That gets mentioned to me often about tdd and as usual, it sounds like it's worth thinking about.  Point taken, I'll see what kind of time I have to roll this out and see if I can inject some helpers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "smuggle" a function (or an *Object* of functions, variables, etc) out of your closure quite easily by [adding an extra parameter to the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6626263/1615483) or hard-coding an early return. The smuggled function should still have the closure from where it was smuggled from unless you're doing something like the evil `eval`.

It might me worth noting that if you're taking functions out like this for testing purposes only, it may be preferable to comment out or otherwise remove the code to access these before publishing it on your website, so it can't be abused. Also, be aware that `this` will change depending on how a function is invoked, if you are using it.

For [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rEDMh/)

```
function createSomething(init, aaa) {
    function privateMethod(param) {
        return init[param];  //assuming this is more complicated, how can you test it?
    }

    function getData() {
        return init.data;
    }

    function getValue(name) {
        if (name === "privateNode" || typeof name !== "string") {
            return "permissionDenied";
        }
        return privateMethod(name);
    }
    // ----------------------------------
    if(aaa) return privateMethod;
    // ----------------------------------
    return {
        getData : getData,
        getValue: getValue
    };
}

var something = createSomething({
    privateNode : "allmysecrets",
    id : "1234",
    data : {
        stuff : "32t97gfhw3hg4"
    }
}, 1); // passing extra arg to get method

console.log(
    something('id'),
    something('privateNode')
) // 1234 allmysecrets
```

Comment: To take it a bit further (excellent suggestion, btw) you could make that secondary param be a test config object that could allow for a testing abstraction layer to allow testing for only one function at a time.  This would prevent abuse in that the end user would never have access to all the internals.  I'm loving this, thanks!

Comment: @Shane, yes, you can add more abstraction layers etc. but you can't really assume anything is _"secure"_ in JavaScript. What I was saying about preventing abuse is more to do with "within the closure" than viewing how it is written.

Comment: agreed, I'm just concerned about API abuse and runtime creation of objects that could manipulate functionality outside the api's authorizations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to export a function that adds test-cases.  It wouldn't export anything that's meant to be out-of-reach (private).

I mostly use Mocha for testing, so I call "describe()" and "it()" from that function that adds tests.  For example, let's say I have created a library called "whatever."  I could create a function "test" (or _test, _addTests, ...):

```
var whatever = (function() {
  var insideClosure = "Ha ha!";
  return {

    // obviously you would have other functions too
    test: function() {
      describe('something', function() {
        it('should work', function() {
          assert.equal(insideClosure, "Ha ha!");
        });
      });
    }
  };
})();
```

Then my ./test/tests.js would have:

```
whatever.test();
```

One obvious bad point with this is the fact that you can't separate pure code and tests (unless maybe by using some kind of deployment workflow).